# Is there any C++ lib to read thumbnails from thumb.db in Windows Folder?

Tags: c++, windows, image

I want to read all thumbnails from a folder with images in Windows XP.
But if I read image file to get thumbnail, it seems a bit slow, so I wish I can first read the windows image thumbnail cache:thumb.db.
Is there any lib in c++ or c to read thumbnails from thumb.db.

Comment: Sorry about that it seems thumbs.db doesn't store images 1 thumbnail per ADS.  I was certain until now that it did as I read it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this useful:

ThumbsDBLib in C++

http://www.windameister.org/blog/index.php/thumbslib-in-cpp

Answer (score 6):

The Thumbs.db file is stored in OLE [Compound Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693383.aspx) format, the same format that many Microsoft Office products use.

You could also try to look into [ThumbsDBLib](http://www.petedavis.net/MySite/DynPageView.aspx?pageid=31).  It is in C# but you can probably see what they do to read the data and convert it to C++.

Note: Windows Vista and later doesn't use Thumbs.db.  See the [IThumbnailCache interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774628(VS.85).aspx) for Vista and later.

For Vista and later they are stored here: %homedrive%\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer

Comment: Thank you Brian!I convert the c#code into c++, it works!. BTW my English Name is also Brian *_*